# Let the openCTI of Salesforce listen to the Softphone javascript events

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, opencti, softphone

I have an Aircall managed package installed in my Salesforce org.

My requirement here is that, once I accept an incoming call in my Softphone widget for Aircall, I have to check the incoming phone number - using Apex, search in my Salesforce org for the corresponding Lead and open the record detail page
I am trying to figure out how to implement it.

I studied the OpenCTI documentation and understood the following :

1. I have to create a Visualforce which will act as a container for the Aircall SoftPhone widget.
2. In the visualforce page itself, I have to add and OpenCTI event listener.
3. Then use a soql query to search for the Lead and open the corresponding record detail page.

However, I am not exactly of my understanding and need some clarification whether my approach is correct or not.